# Selenium Screenshot Works Slow (Python)

Tags: python, performance, selenium, phantomjs, screenshot

Script with selenium and phantomjs which checks around 20 dynamic pages and warn me when there is a change works fast without screenshot part but when I want to get screenshots of the pages it takes around 1-2 minutes to warn me and to get screenshot. Is there a better and faster way to take screenshot of a specific part of page with python?

Here is the code I use for screenshot.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image

fox = webdriver.Firefox()
fox.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')

# now that we have the preliminary stuff out of the way time to get that image :D
element = fox.find_element_by_id('hlogo') # find part of the page you want image of
location = element.location
size = element.size
fox.save_screenshot('screenshot.png') # saves screenshot of entire page
fox.quit()

im = Image.open('screenshot.png') # uses PIL library to open image in memory

left = location['x']
top = location['y']
right = location['x'] + size['width']
bottom = location['y'] + size['height']


im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) # defines crop points
im.save('screenshot.png') # saves new cropped image
```

> SOLVED:
>
> The problem is not about selenium module, either screenshot. It is
>   about phantomjs, after I start using chromedriver it is very fast and more
>   efficent.
>
> SOLUTION UPDATE:
>
> The problem with phantomjs is disabling images. When I use
>   `--load-images=no` I face with the memory leak issue and scripts gets really slower, without it there
>   is no problem.

Comment: Have you determined which part of your code is taking too long? The Selenium screenshot, or the PIL crop? Have you determined what is happening with memory at that time? What is happening with CPU resources at that time?

Comment: Yes I did. For phantomjs memory increases to 3gb and stuck into 3gb until I close it, once I saw 5gb in the activity monitor but it was only once and cpu consuming also increase so much too. The situation is not normal for sure. I think that the problem is about the Selenium screenshot part, because I follow it and see that it crops the full image in a second in folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save some time by cropping the screenshot in memory without saving it first to a file:

```
import StringIO
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
element = driver.find_element_by_id('hlogo')

crop_points = driver.execute_script("""
    var r = arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    return [r.left, r.top, r.left + r.width, r.top + r.height];
    """, element)

with Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(driver.get_screenshot_as_png())) as img :
    with img.crop(crop_points) as imgsub :
        imgsub.save(logo.png', 'PNG')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the fastest part is cropping. I really don't know why but phantomjs consumes memory which is not normal and works very slow. I am using osx with 4gb ram, i5 and phantomjs memory consuming can be up to 3gb. How it can be possible?

Comment: How is it with Chrome? It it as bad? There's probably a memory leak, but without a reproducible example, it's hard to say.

Comment: you won't believe me but it is only 35mb even if I use it with loading images. same script, same conditions. I really don't understand what is wrong with phantomjs. It is up to date. So the problem is not about the script or selenium, the problem is totally phantomjs. Well I am on osx so I cannot make chromedriver headless that's why I had to use phantomjs.

Comment: Also with firefox consuming memory is around 400mb. Cannot use headless too.

Comment: I can only recommend you to use Chrome instead of PhantomJS. If you really don't want the window, then you should start the browser off-screen to hide it.

Comment: I just figured out that the problem with the phantomjs is about disabling images. When I don't use '--load-images=no', there is no problem with the performance. I looked for it and see that it is a known issue/bug for phantomjs.